# Python selenium Headless Chrome. I want to modify Headless chrome True to Flase. But still chenging the chrome option, driver is not going to headless

Tags: python, selenium, headless

I want to modify Headless chrome True to False. But still changing the chrome option, driver is not going to headless. Many many thanks in advance to all

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
options = Options()
options.set_headless(headless=False)
driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='e:\\chromedriver',   
    options=options)
driver.get("http://google.com/")
print ("Chrome Initialized")
time.sleep(5)
options.set_headless(headless=True)
print ("Headless Chrome ") #HEADLESS
driver.refresh
time.sleep(5)
print('Chrome should go Headless now')
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```